# Get StackOverflow exception on web service project but not in winform project

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm trying to understand why I get stackoverflow exception on one project (Web Service) but not on WinForm project..

Here is the code:

```
VimClient vimClient = new VimClient();
ServiceContent serviceContent = vimClient.Connect("https://servername/sdk");
UserSession us = vimClient.Login(username, password);

ManagedObjectReference _svcRef = new ManagedObjectReference();
_svcRef.Type = "ServiceInstance";
_svcRef.Value = "ServiceInstance";

NameValueCollection filterForVM = new NameValueCollection();
filterForVM.Add("Name", ServerName);
VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine)vimClient.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, filterForVM, null);

vimClient.Disconnect();
```

The Exception is on this line:

```
VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine)vimClient.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, filterForVM, null);
```

What could it be?

Comment: you have come to the right place

Comment: We need the Stack Trace.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The code using the vmware sdk, vmware.vim.dll

Comment: Right now Im trying to create a new thread with new stack size..

Comment: Creating new thread with new stack size solved the problem :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Creating new thread with new stack size solved the problem :) thanks